# Why does vector::erase() not invalidate a reference to the erased element?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, reference

Consider the following code:

```
vector<int> test = { 0, 1, 2 };
test.push_back(3);   
int& last = test.back();
test.pop_back();    //now last_elem_ref should be invalid, right?
3 == last; //evaluates to true o.O
last = 5;  // this works just as fine
```

I know that references to nothing don't exist, but I don't know how this works. C++ doesn't have a garbage collector or reference counting (except for smart pointers, of course), so *why isn't the object destroyed when its owner has dumped it?*

Or is it destroyed, and the reference doesn't even reference the value anymore?

*When will it be destroyed, e.g. when will the memory it occupies be freed?* (My personal guess is as soon as the last reference to the object goes out of scope.)

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to use `last`. You shouldn't be surprised at any result.

Comment: @chris just to be clear, is it undefined to use `last` after erasing from the vector or undefined in general?

Comment: @iFreilicht, After it becomes a dangling reference.

Comment: After any operation that may cause vector elements relocation. E.g. `push_back` - if there would be not enough memory and relocation will happen, reference will be left invalid. `pop_back` however should never trigger relocation, so technically it is not a UB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that references to nothing don't exist

Yes they do: just like a pointer, a reference can be invalidated and left dangling if the object it refers to is destroyed. Using an invalid reference gives undefined behaviour.

> why isn't the object destroyed when its owner has dumped it?

It is. But destroying an object doesn't necessarily make the memory it occupied inaccessible. In this case, the memory is still managed by the `vector`, and accessing it is likely to give you the old value, since nothing has overwritten it. Or it could cause some other form of undefined behaviour.

> When will it be destroyed, e.g. when will the memory it occupies be freed?

When the vector is destroyed, or when it reallocates its array, the memory will be freed. It might still be accessible though; small blocks are usually returned to a heap for reuse, and not unmapped from the process's memory space.

> My personal guess is as soon as the last reference to the object goes out of scope.

No. As you said, there is no reference counting in C++. Automatic objects are destroyed when they go out of scope, and dynamic objects when they're explicitly destroyed, regardless of any references to them.

Comment: @iFreilicht: When the vector reallocates, all references to elements are invalidated. But it won't reallocate here: that only happens when it needs to grow, or when you call `shrink_to_fit`. In this case, erasing elements (via `erase` or `pop_back`) invalidates references to the erased elements.

Comment: accepted, thank you very much! This answer was thorough and left nothing to question. Honourable mention: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22817552/2533467) which really helped a lot understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reference is still referring to the memory location where the value was, and nothing has changed the contents of that memory location yet.

It's Undefined Behaviour - the contents of that memory, or even the ability to read it without crashing, is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, the memory is still allocated, but this doesn't mean you can use it :-) This is a direct consequence of how `std::vector` manages memory internally. Memory is never freed, unless you `clear()`.

If you try another `push_back`, the value referenced by last should be affected.

Again, to be clear, don't rely on this, it's a bad practice and potentially undefined behavior.

Comment: That little hint with `push_back()` was everything I needed to understand. I forgot that vector has more memory allocated than its elements are occupying.
Thank you very much!
And yes, I would never rely on this as I didn't even expect it to behave that way.